# Call in batch script doesn't go to the specified subroutine in another batch file

Tags: batch-file, call

I have two batch scripts:

Batch_A

```
echo You are in Batch A
call "%~dp0Batch_B.bat" BAR
```

Batch_B

```
:FOO
echo You are in Batch A and you have failed.
:BAR
echo You are in Batch A and you have succeeded.
```

---

For the life of me, no matter which way I syntax it, line 2 in the first batch does not call the "BAR" subroutine in Batch_B.

I've tried it as:

```
 call "%~dp0Batch_B.bat BAR"
 call "%~dp0Batch_B.bat" :BAR
 call "%~dp0Batch_B.bat" %BAR%
 call %~dp0Batch_B.bat BAR
```

Nothing works. I know it's probably something rudimentary, but what am I doing wrong? Are there any other methods of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call a label in another batch-file as far as I know. What you can do is the following:

in Batch_B.bat:

```
Goto %~1
:FOO
echo You are in Batch A and you have failed.
:BAR
echo You are in Batch A and you have succeeded.
```

And in Batch_A.bat

```
call "%~dp0Batch_B.bat" BAR
```

So this will be evaluated to `Goto Bar` in Batch_B.bat and will then go to the second label.

In addition to that you should add `Goto eof` after the end of your `:FOO` part so that you do not go through the `:BAR` part as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it was debated if it is a feature or bug.

```
::Batch_A.bat
@Echo off
echo You are in (%~nx0)
call :BAR
timeout -1
Goto :Eof
:BAR
echo You are in (%~nx0) (%0)
:: this runs's the batch without a call
"%~dp0Batch_B.bat" %*
```

---

```
:: Batch_B.bat
Goto :Eof
:FOO
echo You are in (%~nx0) and you have failed. 
Goto :Eof
:BAR
echo You are in (%~nx0) and you have succeeded.
Goto :Eof
```

---

```
> batch_a
You are in (Batch_A.bat)
You are in (Batch_A.bat) (:BAR)
You are in (Batch_B.bat) and you have succeeded.
```

Comment: The called sub inside batch_a.bat will give different results to `%0` and `%~nx0`. The latter will return the real file while `%0` names the called sub.